# Continuous functions are closed

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, closed-map

I am wondering whether every continuous real valued functions is closed? Apparently it seems that it is really that way. Let B be a closed subset of the domain of f. We show that f(B) is closed. If not then there exists a sequence of values $y_n$  in f(B) that converges to a point b, outside f(B). Then there exists a sequence of values $x_n$ in B such that $f(x_n)=y_n$. Since $y_n$ is convergent and f is continuous, so $x_n$ is also convergent to a point a in B (since B is closed) . Since f is continuous, $f(x_n)=y_n$ converges to $f(a)$ which happens to be a point in B, thus contradicting the fact that $y_n$ converges to a point $b$ outside f(B). Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Not every continuous function is closed. Consider $\arctan$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for the usual topology. Obviously, $\arctan$ is continuous and $\mathbb{R}$ is closed but $\arctan(\mathbb{R})=]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$ is open.

Comment: The fault in your argument is that $x_n$ need not converge or it may not have convergent subsequence unless the domain is bounded. If $B$ is closed and bounded then $f(B)$ is closed and bounded

Comment: One quick addition. If you are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the domain $K$ of your continuous function $f$ is compact, then $f$ is a closed mapping. To see this, let $F\subset K$ be a closed set. Notice that $F$ is bounded (since $K$ is bounded) and closed so it is compact. Then $f(F)$ is compact, and thus closed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this discussion. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then there exists a sequence of values $x_n$ in $B$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$. Since $y_n$ is convergent and $f$ is continuous, so $x_n$ is also convergent to a point a in $B$ (since $B$ is closed).

Not quite. It's true that if $x_n$ converges then $f(x_n) = y_n$ also converges, but the converse does not hold. For example, if $f$ is the constant map $0$, then $y_n = 0$ is the only option. But, we can make literally any sequence $x_n$, and it will satisfy $f(x_n) = y_n$. So, think of a sequence that's as non-convergent as you can make it, use it for $x_n$, and it will be a counterexample to this logic.

That said, constant functions are indeed closed. If you want a counterexample, consider
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}.$$
Then $\Bbb{R}$ is closed, and $f(\Bbb{R}) = (0, 1]$, which is neither open nor closed. In particular, if we take any $y_n \to 0$, then inevitably we must have $|x_n| \to \infty$, and therefore $x_n$ cannot be convergent.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing it out to me in so much detail.

Comment: You're welcome!